# Hit Test Image Content

Tags: wpf, bitmap, hittest

I want to hit test the content of an image. In order to do that I created `BitmapImage` and draw it inside `DrawingVisual` using `DrawingContext.DrawImage()` method. When it is hit tested, using `VisualTreeHelper.HitTest()`, every point in image returns true however I want white pixels to return false and non-white pixels to return true. So I converted `BitmapImage` to black and white pixel format using `FormatConvertedBitmap` but it didn't work also. Any suggestions? It would be better if I can hit test against `ImageDrawing` object.

Answer (score 1):

Two suggestions:

1. Try using transparent pixels, not
   white
2. You may need to implement your own [hit testing logic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752097.aspx#overriding_default_hit_testing). For a
   Visual this means overriding
   HitTestCore.

Comment: Transparent pixels don't work. I tried to do custom hit testing in DrawingVisual by getting the ImageDrawing using VisualTreeHelper.GetDrawing(this). I get the ImageDrawing object but I couldn't find a way to do hit testing with it. If it was derived from Geometry instead of Drawing then I could use FillContains(point) method but it isn't.